# Got error when creating pipe in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I create a pipe class which is **get-member-ship-level.pipe.ts**:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'getMemberShipLevel',
  pure: true
})           
export class GetMemberShipLevelPipe implements PipeTransform
{

  transform(value: number, args?: any): any
  {
      return this.getMemberShipLevel(value);
  }

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit()
  {
      localStorage.removeItem("aze");
  }


  getMemberShipLevel(id: number): String
  {
      this.userService.getSexeLibelleByIdUser(id)
      .subscribe(data => 
      {
          let aa = data as string;
          console.log(" ________________ A:" + aa);
          localStorage.removeItem("aze");
          localStorage.setItem("aze", aa);
          console.log("________________ B:" + localStorage.getItem("aze"));
      }, error => console.log(" ________________ I GOT ERROR" + error));

      let sexe = localStorage.getItem("aze");
      console.log("Id: " + id+ " ________________ C: " + sexe);

      return sexe;
  }

}
```

And **get-member-ship-level.pipe.spec.ts** referencing to [the thread proposed by Sir @GabrielMETZGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970857/angular-unit-testing-a-pipe-that-depends-on-a-service/52971414#52971414) is:

```
import { GetMemberShipLevelPipe } from './get-member-ship-level.pipe';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing' 

describe('GetMemberShipLevelPipe', () => {
  let pipe: GetMemberShipLevelPipe

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed
      .configureTestingModule({
        providers: [UserService]
      })
  })

  it('should create an instance', inject([UserService], (translate: UserService) => {
    pipe = new GetMemberShipLevelPipe(translate)
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy()
  }))
})
```

And in **user.service.ts**, I have:

```
getSexeLibelleByIdUser(id: number): Observable<String>
{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/id/${id}`, {responseType: 'text'});
}

getUsersList(): Observable<any>
{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users`);
}
```

And **users-list.component.html** is

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Sexe</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngIf="!loader">
        <tr *ngFor="let user of userbs | async" style="width: 1500px;">
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{user.id | getMemberShipLevel}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

where `userbs` is defined on the **users-list.component.ts** like:

```
this.userbs = this.userService.getUsersList();
```

My problem is that I got the same value for the different table rows like presented by [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGPEZ.png)

- **Got**: Male Male.                                (WRONG OUTPUT)
- **Expected**: Male, Female.      (CORRECT OUTPUT)

Could you please tell me how I missed ?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971414/5058468

Comment: Hello Sir @GabrielMETZGER, thanks for your help. The error disappears. But nothing changes as output. I got the same value for different table rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not subscribe to the observable inside your Angular Pipe.
Instead try the following:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

@Pipe({
  name: 'getMemberShipLevel',
  pure: true
})           
export class GetMemberShipLevelPipe implements PipeTransform
{

  transform(value: number, args?: any): any
  {
      return this.getMemberShipLevel(value);
  }

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit()
  {
      localStorage.removeItem("aze");
  }

  getMemberShipLevel(id: number): String{
  {
      return this.userService.getSexeLibelleByIdUser(id).pipe(
        tap(data => {
          let aa = data as string;             
          localStorage.setItem("aze", aa);
        }),
        catch(err => {
          console.log(" ________________ I GOT ERROR" + error));
        })
      ))
  }

}
```

And when you want to use the pipe you should add the async pipe behind

```
{{ yourvariable | getMemberShipLevel | async }}
```

Comment: Hello Sir @GabrielMETZGER, I got the error presented by the image that I added recently to your reply. Could you please take a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz that recreate the issue? It is really difficult to debug without it.

Comment: Ok Sir. Thanks for your attention. I made changes on my question. Could you please take a look ?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On my solution the return type of the getMemberShipLevel function should be an Observable<String> instead of String

Comment: That is it Sir @Gabriel METZGER. Thanks a lot for your help. You save my day. Big thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `new GetMemberShipLevelPipe();` you have no arguments in your brackets, however your function `getMemberShipLevel(id: number)` needs to take in an ID, When you call `GetMemberShipLevelPipe` you have to put a numerical ID in the brackets so that it can be used throughout that function.

Comment: Yes Sir @PartyRing. Thanks for your reply. I'm aware from my problem. I made some changes on my question. Could you please take a look. Thanks a lot.